# Issue in Pyspark code when running Glue Script

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

```
import sys
import boto3
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])





sc = SparkContext()
#sc.setLogLevel('DEBUG')
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

#logger = glueContext.get_logger()
#logger.DEBUG('Hello Glue')
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)



# ####connect to database
client = boto3.client('glue', region_name='XXXXXX')
response = client.get_connection(Name='XXXXXX')
connection_properties = response['Connection']['ConnectionProperties']
URL = connection_properties['JDBC_CONNECTION_URL']
url_list = URL.split("/")
host = "{}".format(url_list[-2][:-5])
new_host=host.split('@',1)[1]
port = url_list[-2][-4:]
database = "{}".format(url_list[-1])
Oracle_Username = "{}".format(connection_properties['USERNAME'])
Oracle_Password = "{}".format(connection_properties['PASSWORD'])

#print("Oracle_Username:",Oracle_Username)
#print("Oracle_Password:",Oracle_Password)
print("Host:",host)
print("New Host:",new_host)
print("Port:",port)
print("Database:",database)
Oracle_jdbc_url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"+new_host+":"+port+"/"+database
print("Oracle_jdbc_url:",Oracle_jdbc_url)
source_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", Oracle_jdbc_url).option("dbtable", "xxgmdmadm.vendor_data").option("user", Oracle_Username).option("password", Oracle_Password).load()
#store the value in array 
qrys = source_df.select("SRC_QUERY").collect()
var='select DNB_RESULTS_DTL_ID,REQUEST_ID,source_id,dnb_level   from (select  max(request_id) over(partition by org_code ) max_request_id,a.* from XXGMDMADM.MDM_DNB_RESULTS_DTL a   where  dnb_level =''LVL1'' and request_id in (131) ) where MAX_REQUEST_ID=request_id'
dnb_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", Oracle_jdbc_url).option("query", var).option("user", Oracle_Username).option("password", Oracle_Password).load()
```

error I am getting while populating dnb_df

> An error occurred while calling o111.load. ORA-00911: invalid
> character

Not getting what is wrong with this part

> var='select DNB_RESULTS_DTL_ID,REQUEST_ID,source_id,dnb_level   from
> (select  max(request_id) over(partition by org_code )
> max_request_id,a.* from XXGMDMADM.MDM_DNB_RESULTS_DTL a   where
> dnb_level =''LVL1'' and request_id in (131) ) where
> MAX_REQUEST_ID=request_id'

Even when I am running simple query like  getting  same error

> var="select DNB_RESULTS_DTL_ID,REQUEST_ID,source_id,dnb_level from
> XXGMDMADM.MDM_DNB_RESULTS_DTL"

Does query option doesn't work for Oracle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alias while giving a query, works well:

```
.option("dbtable", "(SELECT * FROM schema.tablename) tbl")
```

Comment: When I tried using table option getting error . This is Oracle database    
`dnb_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", Oracle_jdbc_url).option("dbtable", "(select  request_id from  schema.tablename where request_id =131) AS tbl").option("user", Oracle_Username).option("password", Oracle_Password).load()`
> An error occurred while calling o121.load. ORA-00933: SQL command not
> properly ended

Comment: @purnimaBhatia Can you try removing the `AS` in the query? Like this `(select  request_id from  schema.tablename where request_id =131) tbl`

Comment: Problem is resolved on removing "AS"  .option("dbtable", "(SELECT * FROM schema.tablename) ")

Comment: @purnimaBhatia Glad! Updated the answer accordingly, consider upvoting if it helped!